# Blender with Lubuntu is a disaster , any solution?

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, crash, blender

my hardware - 
4 gigs ddr4 
i5 2.5ghz (integrated graphics)
(not very hi-fi but sails the boat)

i dont do heavy graphics making, blender crashes in making something as simple as a 4 walled room with roof, that too without rendering and without textures, nothing fancy just a simple 4 walled room

also, the saved files dont load with double click, i have to first open blender and then go to open > file

a pain in the ***

any solution or do i need to move back to windows just for blender? 
i like lubuntu more and i am in no mood to switch back, please help

Comment: You haven't specified what Lubuntu you are talking about?  Legacy Lubuntu with LXDE or Modern Lubuntu with LXQt, details we can tell if you provide your release detail.  "*saved files don't load with double click*" means what?  from a file-manager? if so which one (depending on your release this will differ).  Have you disabled double-click?  (release details again are required..)

Comment: I expect you are trying to use v2.80, the [previous versions](https://download.blender.org/release/) had smaller memory requirements. To open a blend file with blender it needs to be in the desktop database, find the `blender.desktop` file that is included with blender - or [download it manually](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/freedesktop/blender.desktop) - and check that it is in the right place, you may also need to run `update-desktop-database`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to play around with my nVIDIA packages and the monitor resolution.Once I got the correct resolution then the graphics would not crash in blender.